# Disconnect from LAN and create separate network

Tags: networking, ethernet

I currently am trying to send a message over ethernet to an embedded device that can only respond to a computer with an IP address ending in .9.  Since the network that I am currently on has that IP address taken, how can I disconnect both my computer and the device from the network, and then create a separate network such that my computer can grab an IP address ending in .9?

Comment: You don't need to create a separate network for it, just set the IP statically on your PC to the .9 IP, then power off the device that currently has it, and restart your PC. It should receive the .9 IP, then start the other device up - if the IP isn't statically set there, it should obtain a different IP. You can Google "static IP {OS}" to find help, where {OS} is your current operating system.

Comment: It's on a work network with several devices on it and I don't know the physical device that is occupying the IP address that I need.

Comment: Are you in IT on the work network? Contact your Network Admin if not. You should be able to use your DHCP server to reserve the IP address via MAC address of your device. It's also possible to create a new subnet within DHCP so you can receive a different .9 address - again though, something you would only want a network engineer / admin to modify.

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how tight your subnet mask is you might be able to do it. E.g. if your network is 192.168.0.0/16 you could take 192.168.1.9 or 192.168.2.9 or 192.168.3.9 etc. If however you subnet mask is restricted to the last octet (192.168.0.0/24) then your pretty much screwed.

Have to say it's a pretty bizarre limitation to have a machine that will only respond to addresses that end in a 9!